# Finding equilibria and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A mathematical model for the growth of a population is 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}-x=f(x), \ \ \ x(0)\ge 0$$
where $x$ is the population density. Find the equilibria and determine  their stability. Sketch $f(x)$

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Just solve $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Okay,but how do I find the roots for such an equation?

Comment: You find one obvious root $x = 0$. Reduce your polynomial to the $4^{\text{th}}$ order, guess another obvious root $x = 1$, reduce again t o the cubic equation. And then you need to use cubic equation formula, but the solution will be nasty. You'll get one real and two complex roots. You can ignore complex roots, if $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Kaster commented, there are two obvious roots to the equation. So write the condition as $$2x^2-x(1+x^4)$$ and use the long division by $x(x-1)$; you are left with $$x^3+x^2+x-1=0$$ As Kaster said, using Cardano method for solving cubic equation will give you something ugly for the real solution $$x=\frac{1}{3} \left(-1-\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{17+3 \sqrt{33}}}+\sqrt[3]{17+3
   \sqrt{33}}\right)$$ A simpler way would be consider $$F(x)=x^3+x^2+x-1$$ Its derivative (a quadratic equation) does not show any real root; so there is a single root in the real domain.

Now, by inspection $F(0)=-1$, $F(1)=2$; so the root is between $0$ and $1$. So, let us try Newton method starting with $x_0=\frac 12$. As you know, the iterates are given by $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{F(x_n)}{F'(x_n)}$$ For your case, this could write after some minor simplifications $$x_{n+1}=\frac{2 x_n^3+x_n^2+1}{3x_n^2+2x_n+1}$$ Applying, this gives the following iterates $$x_1\approx 0.5454545455$$ $$x_2\approx 0.5436917653$$  $$x_3\approx 0.5436890127$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.